# mysql DAYOFYEAR return different values (mysql bug with leap year)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Mysql server 
for

```
SELECT 
   DAYOFYEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_birthday, "%Y-%m-%d") ) as birthday_day,
   FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_birthday, "%Y-%m-%d") as usual_date, 
   unix_birthday
FROM workers
```

returns

```
unix_birthday | usual_date | day_number
     246      | 1980-09-02 | 336690000
     245      | 1990-09-02 | 652222800
```

Why the days are different (245 and 246)?

Comment: One might be taking the local time zone into account.

Answer (score 3):

1980 is a [leap year](https://kalender-365.de/leap-years.php), while 1990 is not.

Comment: No, MySQL is correct. Do I truly have to explain what a leap year is? Btw, it is explained in the link I provided.